# Drawing Starbursts – basil.js

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, basil.js

I am trying to draw a starburst by first drawing a polygon and then adjusting its properties.

on indesignjs.de it says a polygon is any shape that is not a rectangle, ellipse, or graphic line. When you add a polygon, InDesign creates a regular polygon based on the current polygon preferences settings. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to draw the damn thing.

I wrote this:

```
    var myPolygon = polygon(0, 0, 10, 10);
    property(myPolygon, "numberOfSides", 8);
    property(myPolygon, "insetPercentage", 50);
```

but I get an error in indesign saying that polygon is not a function. Is is truncated like rectangle is (i.e. poly)?

Comment: There is no polygon function in Basil.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As fabianmoronzirfas pointed out, `polygon()` is not a basil.js function (as opposed to `rect()`). So either you would have to draw the shape yourself using basil commands like this:

```js
beginShape();
  vertex(23, 45);
  vertex(34, 67);
  // draw as many vertices as you need
endShape(CLOSED);
```

or you would have to use proper (non-basil) InDesign scripting commands to shape your polygon. The thing you want to achieve can be done by using the `convertShape()` method, which can be used on any shape, so you could create a rect first and then use this method on the rect:

```js
// @include ~/Documents/basiljs/basil.js;

function draw() {

  var myPoly = rect(50, 50, 200, 200);
  myPoly.convertShape(ConvertShapeOptions.CONVERT_TO_POLYGON, 8, 50);

}
```

Comment: Thanks mdomino! InDesign scripting outside of basil.js is still over my head. Appreciate the help!